# Scrape redirect url.

Tags: node.js, request, scraper

May i know anyway to scrape the web site which is redirect url.
Example:

```
request({ uri: 'http://www.toyota.com.my', encoding: 'binary' },

function (error, response, body) {
      // no response receive

}})
```

I guess is because http://www.toyota.com.my/ does not have html document. 
So it unable to get the response. The real redirect url is http://www.toyota.com.my/index.html.

May i know how to detect the url which doesn't have html response?

Answer (score 3):

The final url is in `response.request.uri.href` and all the redirects are in `response.request.redirects`, which by the way looks like this in this instance:

```
[ { statusCode : 302,
    redirectUri: 'http://www.toyota.com.my/index.html' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me as of `request:2.81.0`

```
console.log(response.request._redirect.redirects);    

[ { statusCode: 302, redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4000/' } ]
```